# Making text stay in a group

Tags: java

I have a fairly simple question regarding Java. I am currently learning Java and one of the homework questions has me stumped. The goal is to create a triangle with the little figure. I believe I have the idea down however, I cannot get the whole figure of the guy to move to the right.

The code I have so far is:

```
public class LittleGuy {
    public static final int NUMBER_OF_GUYS = 5; // determines the number of guys.
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            for (int line = 1; line <= NUMBER_OF_GUYS; line++){
                for (int j = 1; j <= (-5 * line + 25); j++){// uses the algorithm.
                    System.out.print(" ");
       }
        guy();

    }
}
public static void guy(){
    System.out.print("  o  ******\n /|\\ *\n / \\ *");
    System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Basically, the body and the head aren't supposed to be separated. I'm having trouble keeping them together. I am assuming that it is a fairly simple fix I am either unaware of or completely over looking. Any information or thought would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You are only printing out the spaces before the first line of your little guy, inside the `guy()` method, you are still printing the rest of the guy on the first line.

I'd suggest making a `printSpaces(int numSpaces)` method which prints `numSpaces` spaces, and changing the guy method to take the number of spaces to print at the beginning of each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class LittleGuy {

public static final int NUMBER_OF_GUYS = 5; // determines the number of guys.
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        for (int line = 1; line <= NUMBER_OF_GUYS; line++){
            int counter=0;
            for (int j = 1; j <= (-5 * line + 25); j++){// uses the algorithm.
               System.out.print(" ");
               counter++;
   }
    guy(counter);

}
}
public static void guy(int count){

System.out.print("  o  ******");
System.out.print("\n");

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
System.out.print(" ");    

System.out.print("/|\\ *");
System.out.print("\n");

for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
System.out.print(" ");

System.out.print("/ \\ *");

System.out.println();
}
```

}

The problem was : In the `guy()` method you use `\n` to print the guy. But it will not take care of the white-spaces you printed in-order to achieve your algorithm (inside the `for` loop).

How it was solved : place a counter in the `for` loop to count how many white-spaces were printed and use that counter in the `guy()` method to print required white-spaces.